# Why two eccentricities from equation of asymptotes?

Tags: conic-sections

> If the equation of asymptotes of a hyperbola is $3 \mathrm{x}^2+10 \mathrm{xy}+3 \mathrm{y}^2+5 \mathrm{x}+6 \mathrm{y}+\mu=0$, then eccentricity of the hyperbola is/are
> (A) $\sqrt{5}$ 
> (B) $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$
> (c) $\sqrt{3}$
> (D) $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

What I tried:
Angle between pair of straight lines is given by $$\tan\theta=2\dfrac{\sqrt{h^2-ab}}{|a+b|}\\ =\frac43$$
Now I know that eccentricity is given by $$e=\sec(\frac{\theta}{2})$$

By half angle identity, $\sec\theta=\frac{\sqrt5}{2}$

So $$e=\dfrac{\sqrt5}{2}$$

But the given answer is A,B

What am I missing?

Comment: The hyperbola and it's conjugate Hyperbola have same asymptotes. So answer should be both the eccentricities. relation between e of hyperbola and conj. is $\frac{1}{e^2}+\frac{1}{(e_1)^2} =1$